# How to assign image to Circle avatar -flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 30.0,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: (_imageFile != null)
                                  ? Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: FileImage(_imageFile),
                                            fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Image.network(snapshot.data//If url is empty it'll return an error
                                    .photoUrl),//Replace with Image From DB
                              ),
```

The container holds an image if the user changing the picture, else Image from the database will appear but if the `photoUrl` is empty it'll return an error saying 'url != null : is not true' 
if url==null how can I replace the `CircleAvatar` with an `Icon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],//if there's no background image provided
  backgroundImage: (netimage == null)?null:NetworkImage(netimage),//add URL to netimage 
  radius: 25.0,//radius of the circle avatar
),
```

This may help you

Comment: This won't work cause when the `photoUrl` is null it'll return an error!

Comment: Same goes with `NetworkImage`, when the url is null it'll return an error.(saying: url cannot be  null)

Comment: If your url is null, it definitely push an error. You have to provide a condition for that, let me edit my answer.